# Socket Io Client for MAUI / Xamarin

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, socket.io, maui

Is there any packages for a Socket.IO client for MAUI or Xamarin? I tried using `EngineIoClientDotNet` it is not maintained anymore and it is not working. And it seems like most of the socket.io clients for MAUI or Xamarin are deprecated.

**Is there any socket.io client packages for MAUI or Xamarin?**

Comment: Tool recommendations are specifically off topic on SO

Comment: Think about why it is not maintained and "not working". Then think, should you be replacing something not maintained and not working, with something else that will be in similar condition.

Comment: You don't need a package specific to MAUI? There is the one that is linked on the SocketIO github: https://www.nuget.org/packages/SocketIOClient which is up to date. What more do you need?

Comment: I think you can use [SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-7.0) for this. You can definitly use websocket with it and it seems you can connect to third party server with the client ([related question](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/216924/connect-to-third-party-websocket-service-with-sign)), if you can also replace the server SignalR is definitly what you are looking for.